# Slow query when joining by date (calendar table)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to implement [this solution](http://www.media-division.com/using-mysql-generate-daily-sales-reports-filled-gaps/).

I have contacts and calendar table. Contacts has `created_at` timestamp column, calendar has `date` column which is date.

So the query:

```
select contacts.id, calendar.date
from contacts
right join calendar on date(contacts.created_at) = calendar.date
```

never finishes.

I've read that `date(contacts.created_at)` slows it and one of the possible solutions is to separate `created_at` column into two columns: `date` and `time`. But I don't like this solution since I need timestamp column. Is there any other way to handle this case?

Basically this is the famous issue when you get some stats with dates and you need to fill the date gaps with zeros. So maybe it worth a try to handle this in PHP...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generated column to store the date component of the `created_at` column:

```
ALTER TABLE contacts
ADD created_at_date AS (date(created_at)) STORED;
```

You can then `JOIN` on this column as usual.

Note, generated columns are available in MySQL 5.7.5 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have index on `created_at` but the moment you use `date()` optimizer cant use that index because is a different field.

So is better if you create a date column on contact instead that you can index

Or Instead try:

```
select contacts.id, calendar.date
from contacts
right join calendar 
   on contacts.created_at >= calendar.date
  and contacts.created_at < DATE(DATE_ADD(calendar.date, INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```